# Cannot save object to dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, defaultdict

I'm trying to analyse the time difference between any given 2 stages of an online order being sent to restaurant. Here is an overview of what I'm trying to do:

- Iterate through a list of dictionary objects
- Take the difference between two datetime values as total seconds
- Save that difference to another dictionary, using order identifier as key, and total seconds difference as value

Here is an example object from the list that I'm iterating through (all_order_status_sorted[0]):

```
(772101,
[{'Accepted in Restaurant': datetime.datetime(2016, 7, 20, 18, 35, 27),
'Created': datetime.datetime(2016, 7, 20, 18, 34, 45),
'In Kitchen': datetime.datetime(2016, 7, 20, 18, 35, 31),
'Paid - Not Sent': datetime.datetime(2016, 7, 20, 18, 34, 45),
'Sent to Central POS': datetime.datetime(2016, 7, 20, 18, 34, 48),
'billId': 772101}])
```

This is the function I wrote to get difference data between any two stages:

```
def time_between_status(fromstatus, tostatus):

    summed_data = {}

    for order in all_order_status_sorted.items():
        key = order[0]
        order = order[1]
        for data in order:
            time_between = (data[tostatus] - data[fromstatus]).total_seconds()
            #print key, time_between
            summed_data.update({key : time_between})
    return summed_data
```

When I print the data I want to save in summed_data dictionary(see the commented line in time_between function), I can see all the data I want to save. However I keep getting the error below:

```
time_between_status('Created', 'Accepted in Restaurant')

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-231-4e2d16e87842> in <module>()
     16     return summed_data
     17
---> 18 time_between_status('Created', 'Accepted in Restaurant')
     19 print summed_data

<ipython-input-231-4e2d16e87842> in time_between_status(fromstatus, tostatus)
      8         order = order[1]
      9         for data in order:
---> 10             time_between = (data[tostatus] - data[fromstatus]).total_seconds()
     11             print key, time_between
     12             summed_data.update({key : time_between})

KeyError: 'Accepted in Restaurant'
```

It keeps pointing the second argument of the function, and I can't figure out why it doesn't save to the summed_data dictionary, even though it successfully prints those data. What am I missing?

Comment: There's way too much code here for a `KeyError`. Try to show a  [mcve]

Comment: What is `data` you used in creating time_between variable ?

Comment: Are you saying that if you un-comment `#print key, time_between` it prints what you expect? That doesn't seem consistent with the error traceback. Are you _sure_ that `data['Accepted in Restaurant']` exists at that point? It would help if you could post a MCVE that contains an explicit sample `data` that we can run to reproduce your error.

Comment: @Rockybilly  `data` as follows:

`{'Accepted in Restaurant': datetime.datetime(2016, 7, 20, 18, 35, 27), 'Paid - Not Sent': datetime.datetime(2016, 7, 20, 18, 34, 45), 'Sent to Central POS': datetime.datetime(2016, 7, 20, 18, 34, 48), 'Created': datetime.datetime(2016, 7, 20, 18, 34, 45), 'billId': 772101, 'In Kitchen': datetime.datetime(2016, 7, 20, 18, 35, 31)}`

Comment: @PM2Ring Yes, it does print what I expect when I un-comment that line. Does the comment above about `data` provide better info?

Comment: I ran the code like this and it worked. https://codeshare.io/w8CzX, please recheck your variables.

Comment: Try `for key, order in all_order_status_sorted.items():` then remove the assignments for `key` and `order`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show at least one of entries in the global dictionary `all_order_status_sorted` that is being referenced by the `time_between_status()` function.